# Image inside a circle with box content on bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I do this design that can be responsive. That will be 2 column on tablet view and 1 column for mobile view.Here's my code [Image inside a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX62v.png)

```
CSS
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 65px;
}

.bo>img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

HTML
    
        How We Manage
        LOOPTEK is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled 
    it to make a type specimen book.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="bo">
            <img src="imgs/icons/web.png" class="rounded" alt="Events and Activities" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
        </div>
        <div class="bo1 text-center">
          <h5>Web Design</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
         text of the printing and typesetting
         industry. Lorem Ipsum has been </p>
          <button class="btn">viewport</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="bo">
            <img src="imgs/icons/web.png" class="rounded" alt="Events and Activities" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
        </div>
        <div class="bo1 text-center">
          <h5>Mobile App</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
         text of the printing and typesetting
         industry. Lorem Ipsum has been </p>
          <button class="btn">viewport</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="bo">
            <img src="imgs/icons/web.png" class="rounded" alt="Events and Activities" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
        </div>
        <div class="bo1 text-center">
          <h5>Desktop App</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
         text of the printing and typesetting
         industry. Lorem Ipsum has been </p>
          <button class="btn">viewport</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="bo">
           <img src="imgs/icons/web.png" class="rounded" alt="Events and Activities" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
        </div>
        <div class="bo1 text-center">
          <h5>Game App</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
         text of the printing and typesetting
         industry. Lorem Ipsum has been </p>
          <button class="btn">viewport</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example and you can update it with your requirements.

CSS

```css
.caption div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #C8C8C8;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.ratio {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h2>Any image, size doesn´t matter, centered and respecting ratio</h2>
 </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-6">
            <p> Image in to circle</p>
            <div  class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(http://trovacamporella.com/img/trovacamporella-fiat500.png);"></div></div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-6">
            <p> Image in to circle with link</p>
            <a href="http://trovacamporall.com" class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(http://trovacamporella.com/img/trovacamporella-fiat500.png);"></a>
        </div>
     
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
           <div class="img1"><img src="" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="img1"><img src="" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- This uses Bootstrap 4, and you'll need include it either [via a CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) or by downloading and serving it locally.
- `col-sm-12` : It refers to mobile device `(576px to 767px) -> 12`, and represents 1 column
- `col-md-6` : It refers to tablet device `(768px to 992px) -> 6`, and represents 2 columns
- You can read more Bootstrap's structure online. Some good sources are the Bootstrap website and W3Schools. For example, here's some CSS:

  ```
  .img1, .img2 {
      border:2px solid #000;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding:20px;
  }
  ```
- If you want to create a circle image then you need to give height and width first to image, like so:

  ```
  .img1 img, .img2 img {
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      line-height: 100px;
      border-radius:50%;
  }
  ```